# Extracting number from string using regular expression

Tags: regex, tcl

After executing a command

```
if {[execCmd -cmd "xstatus call status" -expectingValue OK -waitTime 5]} {
puts "the Buffer value after executing the command is something like this>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>$buffer<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<\n"
}
```

i got the output as

```
the Buffer value after executing the command is something like this>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>): 
** end
xstatus call status
*s Call 161 Status: Connected
** end

OK<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Now i need the integer value to be extracted from it. How to do it ? I have tried many things but it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can try it like

```
puts [regexp -inline {\d+} $buffer]
```

`\d` will match the any numerical value from 0 to 9. `+` will match one or more occurrence. So together, `\d+` will match one or more occurrence of numerical values.

Have a look at Tcl's man page of [regexp](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/regexp.htm), to know more about the same.

**Note** : We are happy to help you out. But, always show us the code which you have tried.

Comment: so if i use puts [ regexp -inline {\d+} $buffer ]; it will search whole output or a particular line, there is no need to break the line and all

Comment: It will search in the whole output. No need to break the line.

Comment: @Hoodiecrow : Thanks Hoodiecrow. I have updated the answer and will follow those.

Comment: Thanks. It's details, but they matter. Nice answer btw.